# Projection from discrete set in covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Kosniowski's book it is said that a trivial example of covering space is consider the canonical projection $\pi : X \times Y \to X$, being $Y$ a discrete space.

My question is: why $Y$ must be discrete?

Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Discrete space does not mean finite.

A space $X$ is said to be discrete, if all subsets are open (and thus also closed).

Comment: I think that you also can talk about discrete set without a topology.

Answer (score 0):

Discrete does not mean finite. Depending on your definition of a covering space, usually you do allow infinite, discrete fibers. Think for instance of the standard cover of $S^1$ by $\mathbb{R}$ (whose fiber is $\mathbb{Z}$) or of the Riemann surface of the complex logarithm, which is a cover of $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ with fiber $\mathbb{Z}$.

There are generalizations with continuous fibers (for instance, fibered manifolds), but they are usually more complicated than covering spaces.

Comment: Ok, but why $Y$ must be discrete? What happens if one subset is not open?

Comment: It's not that it *must*, it is just the definition. You want each point $x$ in the base space to have a neighborhood $U_x$ such that $p^{-1}(U_x)$ is a disjoint union of spaces, each one homeomorphic to $U_x$. But $\sqcup_{i \in I} U_x  \cong I \times U_x$ iff $I$ is given the discrete topology. The fact that the preimage is a disjoint union of copies of $U_x$ is important and allows you to prove many things. You can choose not to have this property, but then I imagine that some theorems about covering spaces would not be true anymore.

Comment: Ok, thank you (to both) very much for all!  :)